# Converting multiple rows into one in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

I have 2 tables:

**Product**:

```
ProductId | Name  | Description 
----------+-------+-------------------------------------
1         | shirt | this is description for shirt
2         | pent  | this is description for pent
```

**ProductOverride**:

```
ProductOverrideId | ColumnId  | Value                  | ProductId 
------------------+-----------+------------------------+-----------
1                 | 1         | overridden name        | 1
2                 | 2         | overridden description | 1
```

where `ColumnId` is `column_id` from `sys.columns`.

I want to select all the products with the following requirement:

if product name or product description is overridden in ProductOverride table, get the overridden value of name/description, otherwise get the name/description value from the product table.

Sample output:

```
ProductId | Name            | Description 
----------+-----------------+---------------------------
1         | overridden name | overridden description
2         | pent            | this is description for pent
```

I have the following query which returns the exact result.

```
DECLARE @productNameColumnId INT = 1;
DECLARE @productDescriptionColumnId INT = 2;

WITH OverriddenProductNameCTE ([Value], [ProductId]) AS 
(
   SELECT 
       temp.[Value], temp.ProductId 
   FROM 
       ProductOverride temp 
   WHERE 
       temp.ColumnId = @productNameColumnId 
), OverriddenProductDescriptionCTE ([Value], [ProductId]) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        temp.[Value], temp.ProductId 
    FROM 
        ProductOverride temp 
    WHERE 
        temp.ColumnId = @productDescriptionColumnId
)
SELECT 
    p.ProductId,
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT [Value] 
                   FROM OverriddenProductNameCTE opnc 
                   WHERE opnc.ProductId = p.ProductId) 
          THEN (SELECT [Value] 
                FROM OverriddenProductNameCTE opnc 
                WHERE opnc.ProductId = p.ProductId)
          ELSE p.[Name]
    END AS [Name],
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT [Value] 
                    FROM OverriddenProductDescriptionCTE opdc 
                    WHERE opdc.ProductId = p.ProductId) 
           THEN (SELECT [Value] 
                 FROM OverriddenProductDescriptionCTE opdc 
                 WHERE opdc.ProductId = p.ProductId)
           ELSE p.[Description]
    END AS [Description]
FROM 
    product p
```

but in the `CASE` statements, I have the following repetitive code:

```
SELECT [Value] 
FROM OverriddenProductNameCTE opnc  
WHERE opnc.ProductId = p.ProductId
```

which means if the `CASE` statement's first condition is true DBMS will execute the same query again in the `THEN` part.

I want to improve this query both in terms of simplifying the query and in terms of processing.

Also if there is any advantage of using CTEs in this situation?

Comment: Is it only 2 columns, or is that just for the example?

Comment: there are more columns. I have just added 2 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only 2 columns I think the simplest thing you can do is left join twice with coalesce:

```
SELECT p.ProductId
      ,COALESCE(poN.Value, p.Name) As Name 
      ,COALESCE(poD.Value, p.Description) As Description 
FROM Product p 
LEFT JOIN ProductOverride poN ON p.ProductId = poN.ProductId AND poN.ColumnId = 1 
LEFT JOIN ProductOverride poD ON p.ProductId = poD.ProductId AND poD.ColumnId = 2
```

If it's more columns I would suggest pivoting the ProductOverride table and left join to that - Like this (a complete example):

Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ProductId int,
    Name varchar(100),
    Description  varchar(100),
    price int null
);

INSERT INTO Product VALUES
(1, 'shirt', 'Description for shirts', 1),
(2, 'Pants', 'Description for pants', 4),
(3, 'Socks', 'Description for socks', 5)

CREATE TABLE ProductOverride
(
    ProductOverrideId int, 
    ColumnId int, 
    Value varchar(100), 
    ProductId int
);

INSERT INTO ProductOverride VALUES
(1,1,'product 1 name',1),
(2,2,'product 1 desc',1),
(3,3,'7',1),
(4,1,'pants name',2),
--Note: no pants description in the override tabl
(6,3,'8',2);
-- Note: no socks at all in override table
```

The query:

```
SELECT p.ProductId 
      ,COALESCE(override.[1], p.Name) As Name 
      ,COALESCE(override.[2], p.Description) As Description 
      ,COALESCE(CAST(override.[3] as int), p.Price) As Price
FROM Product p 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ProductId, Value, ColumnId -- Columns To use for pivot
        FROM ProductOverride                                
    ) ColumnsToPivot
    PIVOT (
       max (Value)
       for ColumnId in ([1], [2], [3]) -- Values in ColumnId column to make the column names
    ) as pivotedData
) as override ON p.ProductId = override.ProductId
```

Results:

```
ProductId   Name    Description Price
1   product 1 name  product 1 desc  7
2   pants name  Description for pants   8
3   Socks   Description for socks   5
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/YOY97428)

Comment: your PIVOT code didnt work. I tried to run it with 2 columns and it is giving this error: Incorrect syntax near 'pivotedData'.

Comment: Yeah, I had a little mix up there. Updated my answer with a complete example.